Transforming a line in an arrow with PyQGIS
I'm working on Python Console of QGIS vers 3.36, my goal at the moment is building a plug-in. Well, I would like rendering the lines symbols as some arrows and then setting their aspect, so changing the width.
So far, I'm not able to do this, how can I resolve this issue? The lines are rendered depending their attribute "numTerr".
Here the code:
"Main"

ctC = cartesiano.fields().indexFromName('numTerr')
unique_idT = cartesiano.dataProvider().uniqueValues(ctC)
categorie = []
for uniT in unique_idT:
    if  uniT != NULL:
        print("unit")
        print(uniT)
        colorR = random.randrange(0,255)
        colorG = random.randrange(0,255)
        colorB = random.randrange(0,255)
        
        gb.colorGraph(cartesiano, colorR, colorG, colorB, uniT, categorie)

def colorGraph(layerA, colorR, colorG, colorB, uniT, categorie):
    arrow = QgsLineSymbol.createSimple({'name' : 'arrow', 'style': 'no'})
    layer_style = {}
    arrow.setColor(QColor.fromRgb(colorR, colorG, colorB))
    layer_style['color'] = '%d, %d, %d' % (colorR,colorG, colorB)
    layer_style['outline'] = '#000000'
    symbolLayer = QgsSimpleFillSymbolLayer.create(layer_style)
    category = QgsRendererCategory(uniT, arrow, str(uniT))
    categorie.append(category)
    renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer('numTerr', categorie)
    

    if renderer is not None:
        
        layerA.setRenderer(renderer)
    
    layerA.triggerRepaint()
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layerA)


